# display Text, Textfield & Button in one line

Tags: php, html, css

visit  [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

search for "check" using CTRL + F, than you can see :

[image]

I wanted to display like this as [link2](http://www.flipkart.com/peacock-basic-architect/p/itmdzdt44rzemzjf?pid=BLCDCYYHKPY9UVMG&ref=L%3A-2686337306475674626&srno=p_1&query=peacock+block+toys&otracker=from-search)

[image]

we are using following code :

**css**

```
font: 12px/1.35 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 2px 8px !important;
    border: 1px solid FFFFFF;
    color: FFFFFF;
    height: 29px;
    line-height: 29px;
    border-radius: 0;

}


.catalog-product-view button.button span span {
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    text-align: center;
```

**Phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_postcode"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                <img src ="http://totaltoys.com/media/font-100.png" height= '35' width= '70'> 
                    <input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should try display: inline on label and input box. What is happening right now is your elements span across entire line. This is my opinion since I'm not that good at CSS.

Comment: thats fine, please post answer with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your HTML like this:

```css
li.item {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
li.item img {
  opacity: .3;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
}
li.item label {
  color: #aaa;
  font-family: 'ubuntu';
}
li.item .search {
  margin-left: 6px;
}
li.item .search input {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: .5rem;
}
li.item .search button {
  background-color: #00bfff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .5rem .5rem;
}
```

```html
<li class="item">
  <img src="http://totaltoys.com/media/font-100.png" alt="" />
  <label for="search">Check availability</label>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter your PIN code"/>
      <button>Check</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: i've updated the post. There is more ways to do that. If you want wast compatibility maybe you don't want use flexbox. You can do it with inline-block too.

Comment: can you please check the link, seems i am missing something in your code.

Comment: yes, i used your code , and this is my updated html: http://pastebin.com/uNnJqYG6 seems i missed here.

Comment: Yeah. You need to adjust a little the HTML code. You are using your HTML code, not mine.

Comment: i am using same html code, but instead of only html , i am using php combined html code.

Comment: can you paste the generated HTML on pastebin please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107040/discussion-between-profile-101-and-mitsu-garcia).

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Answer (score 1):

Add this classes to your CSS file:

```
.actions {
float: left;
margin-top: 9%;
}
ul#shipping-estimation-form {
float: left;
}
```

Comment: i placed code in wrong file. check the link now, its much better than before.